# removing duplicates in nsarray

Tags: iphone, nsarray, duplicates

how can i remove duplicates in nsarray. for instance my array contains following data. I want to compare with adjacent dates to avoid duplicates but it throughs error.

Can anyone guide me what i am going wrong

calendar first-

```
( 
2010-09-25 17:00:00 GMT,
"AAA",
2010-09-25 17:00:00 GMT,
"AAA",
2010-09-26 17:00:00 GMT,
"BBB",
2010-09-26 17:00:00 GMT,
"BBB",
2010-09-27 17:00:00 GMT,
"CCCC",
2010-09-27 17:00:00 GMT,
"CCC",
2010-09-28 17:00:00 GMT,
"AAA",
2010-09-28 17:00:00 GMT,
"AAA",
2010-09-29 17:00:00 GMT,
"DDDD",
2010-09-29 17:00:00 GMT,
"DDDD",
2010-09-30 17:00:00 GMT,
"BBBB"
)
```

my code

```
NSArray dates; //dates contain above values
NSMutableArray *temp_date = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<[dates count]; i+=2){
    BOOL day;

    if ([dates count]-2 >i) {
        day = [[dates objectAtIndex:i] compare:[dates objectAtIndex:i+2]];
    }   

    if (day) {
        [temp_date addObject:[dates objectAtIndex:i]];
        [temp_date addObject:[dates objectAtIndex:i+1] ];
    }
}
```

Regards,
sathish

Comment: What did you try and what is the error you get?

Comment: i added the code over in my post

Comment: Are you trying to say that the array is all strings? Or alternating NSDates and strings?

Comment: u could use isEqual method of NSObject . which compare the object content equality.

Comment: Brother, with all respect, there is a conceptual mistake here. The point is, if you need a NSArray with non duplicate guarantee, actually what you really need is a NSSet. The point is, sometimes we are just to comfortable in use a given data structure and we don't even think the real needs of the application.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could use sets. Duplicates will be removed automatically upon creation.

```
NSArray *cleanedArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:dates] allObjects];
```

Bear in mind that a set is unordered.

As per Brent's comment, a more recent solution to the problem that will allow you to keep the elements in order.

```
[[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:dates] array]
```

Comment: Joseph problem is it is dates is 2d array [[date1 - value],[date1 - value],[date2 - value]]  I have remove duplicate date alone and and value corresponding should be as it is.                                           I mean array has consective values(date,value,date,value etc..)

Comment: Do you want to end up with just one value for each date? Or can one date be in the array multiple times, if the values are different?

Comment: Yes Joseph right- it should end up with one value. for example 2 dates  has same value only we have remove one of it(but value can be duplicated it should not be removed)(i mean just union of dates alone in 2d array)

Comment: i mean exactly like this (14/12/2010,paid,15/12/2010,pending,15/12/2010,pending,16/12/2010,paid) should be (14/12/2010,paid,15/12/2010,pending,16/12/2010,paid)

Comment: How about wrapping those two values (date and status) in an object, putting that in the array and then removing duplicates with an NSSet?

Comment: If you're targeting iOS 5 or higher, or Lion or higher, you can now use `[[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:dates] array]` to deduplicate an array while preserving the order of its elements.  (I believe it keeps each duplicated element at the first index, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: @JosephTura Can you edit your answer with Brent comment. It will be useful to others.

Answer (score 9):

Cleanest way

`NSArray *noDuplicatesDates = [dates valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];`

Comment: This is beautiful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To find identical objects you should better use `–indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:` or –`indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:inRange:`

Answer (score 1):

use this if you have used mutableArray.

```
NSArray *copy = [mutableArray copy];

NSInteger index = [copy count] - 1;

for (id object in [copy reverseObjectEnumerator]) {

    if ([mutableArray indexOfObject:object inRange:NSMakeRange(0, index)] != NSNotFound) {
        [mutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
    index--;
}
[copy release];
```