# nsarray filtering

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsarray, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [removing duplicates in nsarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966592/removing-duplicates-in-nsarray)

Hi friends,

I am storing the value in nsarray and i have to remove the duplicate dates.i mean exactly like this (14/12/2010,paid,15/12/2010,pending,15/12/2010,pending,16/12/2010,paid) should be (14/12/2010,paid,15/12/2010,pending,16/12/2010,paid). can any one suggest me the best way for removing duplicates that has 2 different day in it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSDictionary,  with key = NSDate and value = status (paid/pending). When you insert any date in the dictionary, check dictionary's objectForKey: NSDate, if it returns nil, then you can insert the new date.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [NSSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSet) (our NSMutableSet).

The objects in a set must respond to the NSObject protocol methods hash and isEqual: (see NSObject for more information).
See the [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Sets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000136-CJBDHAJD)

An other solution is to loop of each element of the array to add the element in an other array (mutable) if it is not duplicated:

```
NSMutableArray* filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (id obj in array) {
  BOOL duplicated=NO;
  for (id objTest in filteredArray) {
    if ((obj.date==objTest.date) && (obj.status==objTest.status)) {
      duplicated = YES;
    }
  }
  if (duplicated==NO) {
    [filteredArray addObject:obj];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this would work with the only partially different items?

Comment: Exact if object has more field...

Comment: hi benoit data is on nsarray. it doesnot have key-value pair