# NSSortDescriptor using sort an Array

Tags: iphone, nssortdescriptor

I want to sort an array Using the NSSortDescriptor does not remove the duplicates in my array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSSortDescriptor only sorts, it doesn't remove duplicates. You have to remove duplicates first  you might like to check :

[removing duplicates in nsarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966592/removing-duplicates-in-nsarray)

then use NSSortDescriptor

Comment: I wont donwvote, still someone can,  but I am fed up with SO, few great minded people often downvotes me on either way... if order is not maintained, or if order is maintained (as in this question)... i got +1/-1... finally i removed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, create a `NSSet` from your array and sort that?